# Shopify Cart Webhooks - Extra data

Tags: shopify, webhooks, shopify-app

I have a Shopify app which uses Shopify Webhooks to monitor cart changes. I use the carts/create and carts/update webhook events.

Documentation Link : https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/webhook

The issue is that sometimes I get data that does not display in the Shopify dashboard, meaning that the data that Shopify sends us via their webhook is extra than what they show in their dashboard.

My question is that has somebody else faced this issue and is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Are you comparing the cart create data with order create ? What extra data, like lineitems ?

Comment: @BilalAkbar Hi, I mean random cart/update and cart/create webhook notifications/events, that are generated erroneously by Shopify, as these Add to cart events aren't reflected in the Shopify Admin dashboard.

Comment: Don't know where you are seeing the cart info in Shopify Admin. If you are talking about Abandoned carts, even then it does not make sense to compare that with Cart create  /update. Those events are not erroneous and cart update and create event does not gurantee that order will be created. if you can explain what you are trying to achieve, then may be someone can advise a better solution.